# Database for android mobile application

Tags: java, android, database, mobile

This is a rookie question at best but here goes anyway,

I developed an android mobile application with eclipse, and my task now is to create a database (quite large) to complete my project,
I spoke to my boss about it because i found a lot of links on the web talking about sqlite databases, but this isnt what's required for this app, the data is not to be stored on the device.

My question is, in the of a android mobile app, what database should i use, which tool, how to access it? I really need help understanding, so if any of you guys has experience in this matter i could use some.

Thanks

Comment: you'll have to set up a server..and you can use webservices to connect to the created server..that would be the easiest one..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you say Sqlite is about storing in the device. .
It does depend on the complexity/scale of your database.. and also the expertise and learning curve that you or moreover your company are prepared to invest in.
Also where is it to be located? I have just been and am going through this myself and chose Microsoft Azure to host it. There you can choose what you want to do whether you choose a NodeJS approach and then go with something like Mongo DB or set up a 'website' with sql and all those good things. 
If I were implementing a simple mobile only app with simple ie not complex storage I would take the former approach. The project I am doing also needs a website and my expertise happens to be sql so I chose the latter. That doesn't mean I couldn't have done the former if I had the time to invest in learning Mongo and node.. which is why it depends:-) Hope that helps.
Ps. Azure is worth a look though as you can get going really easy and it looks like it scales well. Of course there are others to consider.